# Call to POST to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events not working

Tags: calendar, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-calendar

I tried search most of today and not finding the root of my issue. I registered an app and copied the ids as needed to make calls to the Microsoft Graph API.

On making a GET call to users/xxxxxxx-f192-4758-xxxx-3f1c27ee5ef9/events, I do get back all my events in the Calendar.

But the issue is, when making a POST call to me/events using the data below:

```
        $calendarEventData = array
        (
            'subject' => 'Test event in my calendar',
            'start' => array
            (
                'dateTime' => '2020-12-22T15:14:14.524Z',
                'timeZone' => 'UTC'
            ),
            'end' => array
            (
                'dateTime' => '2020-12-22T17:14:14.524Z',
                'timeZone' => 'UTC'
            ),
            'body' => array
            (
                'content' => 'This is some hard coded body content',
                'contentType' => 'text'
            )
        );
```

I get back a *HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden returned for "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events"*. I have ensure that the API permissions for Calendars.ReadWrite does exist and consent has been granted too (even redid that to seee if that makes a difference)

Please advise where I am going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution I provided below help your problem ? If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: If still have any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be caused by you assign the permission `Calendars.ReadWrite` in **Application** type(but not **Delegated** type) and you use client credential flow to do authentication. As client credential flow doesn't require you input username and password, so the access token will not contain the user information. When you request the api `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events`, the api backend don't know who is `me`. So it shows 403 error message.

To solve this problem, you can use the object id of "me" to replace `me` in your request api. Like `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/{user object id}/events`.

Comment: OK great - thanks for the help, @Hury ... Yes, that did help. I also had some issues with the way the JSON data was being pushed. But after some trial and error and your comment, it works! Thank you